# What's the best solution for re-rendering child components on props change in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent component that fetches data in **componentDidMount()** hook. The state is **setState()**-d with this data. Then I pass the data to the child components as props and set their state based on these props. On the first render the props will be undefined because **componentDidMount()** hasn't executed yet. So, the child components get undefined props and the state is created with them. When the data fetches in **componentDidMount()** new props are passed to the child components, but the state is already created with undefined props and nothing changes. So, I am aware of two solutions now:

> - Use **componentWillRecieveProps()**. But this is now deprecated.
> - Use stateless child components. Pass the data to them as props from
>     the parent component and don't set a state(use the data from props),
>     and when the parent does a **setState()** in **componentDidMount()**, this
>     will cause a re-render to child components with new props and
>     everything works.

Now, what if I want to have stateful child components? I can't use the second method, and the first one is deprecated. What is the best solution to accomplish this?

Comment: I'd suggest another approach. Parent component's data should passed and handled as **_props only_**. Don't place passed props to child component's state. The latter should only contain data specific to this component. In this case you'll have no the above problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can read [this blog post](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key).
In short a better approach would be to use fully uncontrolled component with key.

1. Add a key to the child component based on data. If the data changes, the key changes and child component will re-mount.
2. Provide data as props to the child, use this props as default state of child component.

Here is a [sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/q77ky89m44)

Answer (score 1):

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state)
```

is invoked right before calling the render method, both on the initial mount and on subsequent updates. It should return an object to update the state, or null to update nothing.
This method exists for rare use cases where the state depends on changes in props over time.

```
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState){
   if(nextProps.someValue!==prevState.someValue){
     return { someState: nextProps.someValue};
   }
    else return null;
  }
```

For more details [enter link description here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)

Comment: But, read https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html, before using this.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the replacement for `componentDidReceiveProps`, `getDerivedStateFromProps`, if you have state within a component which is informed by the values of the props it receives.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops